# C++ Operator Overloading And Protected Fields

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm learning C++ and we've been assigned the task of implementing Vector3D classes using Stack and Heap memory. By accident, I've noticed that it is possible to access the protected member fields x, y and z of the Vector3DStack object v being passed into the overload + method.

```
class Vector3DStack
{
public:
    Vector3DStack(double, double, double);

    double getMagnitude() const;

    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
    double getZ() const;

    Vector3DStack operator + (Vector3DStack);
    Vector3DStack operator - (Vector3DStack);
    Vector3DStack operator * (double);
    Vector3DStack operator / (double);
    Vector3DStack operator % (Vector3DStack);

    double operator * (Vector3DStack);

protected:
    double x, y, z;
};
```

Why does C++ allow access to the x, y and z protected fields on the Vector3DStack parameter v when they are declared as protected? I would have expected to have to use v.getX(), v.getY() and v.getZ().

```
Vector3DStack Vector3DStack::operator + (Vector3DStack v)
{
    return Vector3DStack (x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
}
```

Many thanks,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have implemented `operator+` function as member function.

In case of

```
Vector3DStack operator + (const Vector3DStack& v);
```

it doesn't really matter - it's adding two objects of *Vector3DStack* class.

It matters if it comes to

```
Vector3DStack operator * (double s);
```

In that case you can only have `Vector3DStack` as left value, so:

```
... 
vec = vec + 5; // is ok
vec = 5 + vec; // isn't
```

For the second version you need to implement overloading outside the class:

```
Vector3DStack operator * (double s, const Vector3DStack& v);
Vector3DStack operator * (const Vector3DStack& v, double s);
```

in that case operator function won't be able to reach private members of class `Vector3DStack`.

In this case you could declare operator function as *friend* - friend functions have access to private members of class.

Additional update: you should pass the object by const reference.

Comment: So you can access private and protected fields and methods of a parameter provided they are of the same type?

Comment: *"you should ... return a reference as well"* -- No, you definitely should not return a reference.  Not for these operators.  What exactly are you returning a reference to? The calling object? So you're modifying the calling object and returning it? Most people would be pretty surprised if `operator+` or `operator*` modified either of their operands.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Even though it is a member function, I surely should not be able to access private and protected methods of objects being passed by value?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson: Yes, you surely should.  Member functions of a class have access to all public, protected or private members of any object of that class.  The class is the basic unit of encapsulation, there is no reason to restrict a class' access to itself.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson: With my limited Java knowledge, I was able to scrap together this example -- http://ideone.com/2Xzo3r -- which compiles and runs just as I would have expected.  So I'm curious as to why the behavior of this C++ is surprising to someone coming from Java, since the behavior in Java appears to be the same.